# iOS In App store (storeKit)

Tags: ios, mobile, in-app-purchase

Perhaps this is a dumb question, considering the detailed information about the "In App Purchases" mechanism detailed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1).

I am developing an app with many grouped sequential UIViews (like-stages). Every UIView is generally a mini-game (it offers rich interaction). I would like to use "In App Store" for downloading groups of sequential UIViews and present them to the user. I am afraid this is not possible due it's dynamic execution requirements, however I would like to have suggestions on how to achieve this kind of behavior.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest option is to use an identifier, so when it is purchased, you can access a certain view, kind of like an "unlock code" to a UIView that is built-in to your app.

Comment: The problem is that new groups of sequential UIViews will be added after the app is on the app store. What I need "would" fit in the subscription schema.